# ffmpeg - Cannot use rename on non file protocol, this may lead to races and temporary partial files error

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm getting the following error when I convert my video to hls

```
Cannot use rename on non file protocol, this may lead to races and temporary partial files
```

As far as I can see, it doesn't cause any problems, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the command I use to convert to HLS:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Video\my_video.mp4" -codec: copy -start_number 0 -muxdelay 0 -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls "C:\Video\hls\my_video"
```

I'm not doing any re-encoding or any renaming.

Comment: The condition check for that warning isn't robust. Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the message is logging from the tool only.

Please try with:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls output.m3u8`